# Acessing data from a recently created iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

let me explain what my objectives are first, then i'll explain my problem.
I have a page with several links, and i want to acess this links without entering in the page itself. So i'm using a script to create an iframe of the clicked link and getting the informations from there(page title and some tags contents). I'm managed to create the iframe, wait until it loads and close it after,but i`m not getting any info from the iframe as i wanted yet.**

my code is this:

```
function gerar_info(link, id) {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = "iframe_"+id;
iframe.src = link;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  $("iframe_"+id).ready(function() 
    {
    console.log("iframe_carregado");
    console.log("iframe_"+id);
    var titulo=$("#iframe_"+id).contents().find(".player-title").find("h1").text();
    console.log(titulo);
    //document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    });
}
```

its ny way to get the informations easier, and how can i access the tags within the iframe.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the `<iframe>` content from your own site? If not, the browser won't allow JavaScript code in your page to access anything there.

Comment: As @Pointy mentions, for direct control over the DOM within the iframe, the iframe and the main page must be on the same domain. However, there are work-arounds. If you can modify the page within the iframe, you can use `postMessage` to send and receive information and call JavaScript functions within the other page.

Comment: You'll find these helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Yes, my page its on the same domain, as i said i want to create a iframe from a page link in the site, my intention is to get a information from a page without leave my original page. Im on a page that has some pictures and videos thumbnails, and them are linked to the content pages, i want to extract information that isnt available on the thumbnails page, only on the content page.